# DEADLINE_EXCEEDED while reading logs from Google Cloud Logging

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

My code is based off the sample mentioned on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#logging_list_log_entries-php):

```
use Google\Cloud\Logging\LoggingClient;

$filter = sprintf(
    'resource.type="gae_app" severity="%s" logName="%s"',
    strtoupper($level),
    sprintf('projects/%s/logs/app', 'MY_PROJECT_ID'),
);

$logOptions = [
    'pageSize' => 20,
    'resultLimit' => 20,
    'filter' => $filter,
];
$logging = new LoggingClient();

$logs = $logging->entries($logOptions);
foreach ($logs as $log) {
    /* Do something with the logs */
}
```

This code is (at best) slow to complete, and (at worst) times out on the `foreach` loop with a `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If your query does not match the first few logs it finds, Cloud Logging will attempt to search *your entire logging history* for the matching logs.

If there are too many logs to filter through, the search will time out with a `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` message.

You can fix this by **specifying a time frame** to search from in your `filter` clause:

```
// Specify a time frame to search (e.g. last 5 minutes)
$fiveMinAgo = date(\DateTime::RFC3339, strtotime('-5 minutes'));

// Add the time frame constraint to the filter clause
$filter = sprintf(
    'resource.type="gae_app" severity="%s" logName="%s" timestamp>="%s"',
    strtoupper($level),
    sprintf('projects/%s/logs/app', 'MY_PROJECT_ID'),
    $fiveMinAgo
);
```